# Unable to find locator for validation error message in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image: 1][1][1]

[image: 2][2][2]

1. In below image1 "Name field" validation is Maximum 10 character
2. For the displayed error message no locator is found
3. Image2 is HTML code for the error message...Here if i click on that particular line it will hide
4. This error messages are display from jquery error message validation plugin

Comment: What locators have you tried? Would not `//span[@class=contains(., 'maxlength label-danger')]` do it?

Comment: I'll try this one... Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please let me know, if it worked.

Comment: Its working thank you for helping..

Comment: actual result not found                                    
 "java.lang.AssertionError: expected [最大入力文字数は10文字です] but found []"

Answer (score 1):

You can check with if condition, with the use of below method to get validation message,

```
String findValidationMessage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='Your class name']")).getText();
```

Comment: I'll try this one... Thanks for helping.